# PRISM model checker, Library not loaded: ../../lib/libdd.dylib after upgrading to OSX El Capitan

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan

I just upgraded my mac to El Capitan. I'm trying to run the prism model checker which works well in Yosemite and came across the following error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   /Users/xxx/Applications/prism-4.2.1-osx64/lib/libjdd.dylib:
>   dlopen(/Users/xxx/Applications/prism-4.2.1-osx64/lib/libjdd.dylib, 1):
>   Library not loaded: ../../lib/libdd.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /Users/xxx/Applications/prism-4.2.1-osx64/lib/libjdd.dylib   Reason:
>   image not found

But I checked the lib folder, *libjdd.dylib* is there.

Comment: I emailed the developer of PRISM. They provide the solution. The problem is there are several different 'java' executables linked together, some of which cause this error and some of which do not. Replace the value of PRISM_JAVA in the prism script with the path of another version of java directly. For me, I replaced it to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Update your java path in the prism.

1. Open the prism executable (prism-osx/bin/prism) in a text editor.
2. Edit the line PRISM_JAVA=java   to

PRISM_JAVA="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java"

Or whatever the path of your java is which you can find using
"sudo find / -name java"

3. Save and now execute the prism or xprism.

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I followed user3056166's suggestion and it worked.

I search for the java path using "sudo find / -name java", and find that there are more than one version existing in the system.
I changed PRISM_JAVA in the bin/prism to the path of the latest java. In my mac which is
PRISM_JAVA="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java".

And the problem was solved.